# Using Greek letters with dynamic subscript

Tags: r, plot, expression

I need to use a Greek letter with dynamic subscript in rplot main title. If I use expression and paste, as I did in the 'main' statement in the code below, then the value of the subscripts wont appear as a number but as a letter. I can use paste only to get the value of the subscript, see the 'sub' statement in the code below, but in this case, Greek letters wont be appear!!

Any idea..

Thanks

```
#  Generating Random Variables

#  Exponential(1)

inv.cdf=function(n, lambda){
  u=runif(n,0,1)
  x=-log(1-u)/lambda
}


nu=sample(1:15,6)
y=matrix(rep(NA),10000,length(nu))
for(j in 1:length(nu)){
for (i in 1:10000){
  y[i,j]=2*sum(inv.cdf(nu[j], 1))
}
}

par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
for(j in 1:6){
hist(y[,j], freq=F, main=expression(paste('Histogram of Generated ',chi[2*nu[j]], ' Data')), sub= paste('Degrees of Freedom = ', nu[j]), xlab=expression(paste('Generated ' ,chi^2 ,' Data')))
curve(dchisq(x, df=2*nu[j]),add=T, col=2, lwd=2)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `substitute` which allows you to substitute certain value in the expression (`j` in your case) with any value you like. So, if you use this:

```
main=substitute(
        expression(paste('Histogram of Generated ',chi[2*nu[j]], ' Data')),
        list(j=j)
      )
```

in your `hist` function, it will work.